# Problems installing a custom theme to SassDoc

Tags: sass

The theme I want to install: https://github.com/sassdoc/sassdoc-theme-default which i renamed to "foo" and put into my `project/docs/sassdoc/` folder along with my config.

I've managed to generate a very basic SassDoc based on my current SASS. My trouble is installing a custom theme.

My directory structure and config are as follow:

```
 - project/
   - dist/
     - docs/
       - sassdoc/ (generated - destination)  
   - docs/
     - sassdoc/ (personal sassdoc folder to store files)  
        - config.json (config file)
        - foo/ (theme folder that i want to install)
   - src/
     - _assets/  
       - sass/ (sass source)
```

config.json

```
{
   "theme": "foo"
}
```

I generate my SassDoc with `sassdoc project/src/_assets/sass project/dist/docs/sassdoc project/docs/sassdoc/config.json` aka `sassdoc source dest config`.

I get an error saying theme "foo" is not found. I'm not clear on how I should be installing a theme.

Comment: Please, open an issue on https://github.com/sassdoc/sassdoc so we can discuss it.

Comment: Actually, try `./foo`. If it does not work, please open an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The `theme` key of the config file is interpreted as a path only if it contains a `/`. Also note the theme path is relative to the config file, as stated [here](http://sassdoc.com/configuration/#theme).

So as said Hugo, you need `"theme": "./foo"` for it to work.